# How to make my android app's source code difficult to reverse engineer?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I recently was getting started with reversing android application. Any legit apk from google play store when reversed using jadx gave somewhat readable code but the classes and methods were all A, B, C, D and a,b,c,d, etc. This makes is comparatively difficult to understand the code unless I decide to dive into it.

But when I reversed an apk that I developed, it clearly gives names of variables and methods that I had originally used. My question is how can I make my apk difficult to reverse engineer?

Comment: This process of changing the methods and classes names to a, b, c,… is called obfuscation and is very common in software industry.

Answer (score 2):

Proguard, minifying etc is what you are looking for. It is described well [here in the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)